# LINQ and associations - When is an Include() required?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

This LINQ works as expected and brings back the `Department` entity associated with a given `Employee`

```
Employees.Where(e => e.EmployeeId == 10).Select(e => new {e.Department})
```

However a similar LINQ expression fails saying `Department` is null

```
Employees.Where(e => e.EmployeeId == 10).Department
```

The first LINQ statement is able to determine the association between `Employees` and `Department` yet the second LINQ expression cannot. If I use the `Include("Department")` statement in the second LINQ example then it will work and `Department` will not be null.

```
Employees.Include("Department").Where(e => e.EmployeeId == 10).Department
```

Why is Include("Department") not required in the first LINQ statement?

Comment: Are you sure that `Employees.Where(e => e.EmployeeId == 10).Department ` compiles? It shouldn't.

Comment: I am not sure if it compiles. I am testing it inside of LINQPad using my EF assembly. Intellisense doesn't show any errors.

Comment: Also the other one (`Employees.Include("Department").Where(e => e.EmployeeId == 10).Department`) doesn't make sense. Are you sure there isn't a  `First` or `FirstOrDefault` call there?

Comment: The idea is that you probably don't want Linq to pull every possible associated navigation property for your entity as it could result in a huge amount of unneeded data.  The reason the first "works" is because you are actually selecting the Department entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first statement is explicitly asking for Employee.Department object and will only return the department object. What happens is linq builds a sql query that inner joins the department table.

The second statement queries for the employee object. Linq builds a sql query to return the employee object only and since you did not ask for department it does not inner join the department table. After employee object is returned .Department property is being called which is null. The .Department part is called after linq generates the sql query and returns the employee object.

Using include, linq will query for employee table and inner join the department table. This will return both employee and employee.department.

Using select is the best approach because you are returning only exactly what you want. Using include should generally be avoided if possible for performance reasons.